# Pairs of disjoint sets in outer measure definition

Tags: measure-theory

Why the definition of the outer measure $\mu^*$:

$$\mu^*(A) = \inf\Bigl\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n): A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n, A_n \in \mathcal A,\; n \in \mathbb N\Bigr\}$$

is wrong when $A_i \cap A_j \not= \emptyset$, $i \not = j$?

Can someone help me to show that?

Comment: Can rephrase your question. As it stands I don't have any idea what you are asking.

Comment: Why the definition of outer measure (showed above) is only for pairwise disjoint sets?

Comment: In the formula for $\mu^{*}(A)$ the sets $A_i$ are **not** disjoint.

Comment: The formula is for outer measure, and by measure theory $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint. But my question is why? Why I cannot use it for not disjoint sets?

Comment: In the usual definition of outer measure you don't take the sets to be disjoint. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure

Comment: But the countable additivity?

Comment: @Philip The definition of countable additivity involves pairwise disjoint sets because that is what is intuitive. For example, the area of a union of pairwise disjoint sets is the sum of the areas of those sets. Also, if you allowed any collection of sets (not necessarily pairwise disjoint), then the measure would have to be identically 0 (since for any measurable set $A$, $\mu(A) = \mu(A\cup A) = \mu(A)+\mu(A)$).

Comment: Just read the definitions placed on your plate **very carefully** and don't mix them up. If it concerns countable additivity then you will encounter disjointness, if it concerns outer measure then you will not encounter disjointness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but the the following may be insightful. Suppose I also define,

$$\bar\mu^*(A) = \inf\Bigl\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n): A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n, A_n \in \mathcal A\; \text{are pairwise disjoint} \Bigr\}$$

I claim that $\mu^* = \bar \mu^*.$

Since we are taking the infimum over a smaller collection of sets,we have $\mu^*(A) \leq \bar\mu^*(A)$ for all $A \subset X$ (here $X$ is your measure space).

Conversely let $A_n \in \mathcal A$ be a sequence such that $A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n.$ Then we define $B_n \in \mathcal A$ as $B_1 = A_1$ and for $n \geq 2,$
$$ B_{n+1} = A_{n+1} \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i.$$
Observe by construction that $B_n$ are pairwise disjoint and we have,
$$ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n. $$
Therefore we have,
$$ \bar\mu^*(A) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n). $$
Taking the infimum over all sequences $A_n \in \mathcal A$ we deduce that,
$$ \bar\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(A). $$
Hence they are equal.

---

Although these two definitions are the same, the reason we usually don't take pairwise disjoint sequences when defining the outer measure is because it tends to be simpler to work with. If we have a covering of our set $A$ we want to compute the outer measure of, we don't need to go through this construction to get a disjoint covering each time.

Also in practice the technical construction of the outer measure is not too important, beyond the fact that it can be constructed. The important point is that it satisfies certain properties [as outlined on the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure), and the provided definition is the minimal thing that works.